# Index that DISTINCT ON would use in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes, distinct-on

There are 2 tables:

- `challenge`
- `entry` (many entries per each challenge)

To enter a challenge, one would enter their *Email* and *Name* (for the leaderboard) - there is no registration / authentication process, so `email` and `leaderboard_name` are both recorded for each entry right in the `entry` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.entry
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('entry_id_seq'::regclass),
    challenge_id bigint NOT NULL,
    date_created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    is_removed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    total_points integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT entry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

With this approach, the same email value can be used multiple times with a single challenge. In other words, multiple entries with the same email can be created.

Now, the query to get distinct emails with the highest score is quite simple:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (email)
  id as entry_id, total_points
FROM  entry
WHERE challenge_id = 1
  AND is_removed = false
  AND total_points > 0
ORDER BY email, total_points DESC, date_created;
```

Here, we don't want entries that:

- a) were removed by admins (`is_removed = false`)
- b) have zero score (`total_points > 0`)

The `challenge_id = 1` is also essential as it limits the entries to a particular challenge by its ID.

Also, ordering by `date_created` picks the earliest entry for each email if there are many with the same score. This makes sure the entry selected per email is always the same.

**The issue arises when I try to build an index that would be used by the query planner.**

I tried creating indexes on:

- 3 columns: `email, total_points DESC, date_created`
- 5 columns: `challenge_id, is_removed, email, total_points DESC, date_created`

But `EXPLAIN` keeps returning Seq Scan for the `entry` table.

---

Bonus question - how to effectively select only Top N entries by `total_points DESC, date_created ASC`? The simplest way would be to wrap this query with another query, but are there any better ways?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: An filtered index might help, e.g. `on ... ( email, total_points DESC, date_created) where is removed = false and total_points > 0)`

Comment: The index on `(challenge_id, is_removed, email, total_points DESC, date_created)` works for me.